# I rooted my kindle fire hd, installed android. When I video chat in google hangout the mic doesn't work

Tags: root-access, google-hangouts, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

as above. I rooted my kindle with the hope of installing decent apps on it, including all google apps. When I try to video chat in hangouts the mic doesn't work...

Comment: Which custom ROM did you install?